# Calculate multiple divs with changing values

Tags: jquery, html

I want to take a worksheet used in my line of work and transform it to a web app for convenience. This worksheet takes different crimes and criminal history and provides a score for each. those scores are then calculated and the sum total score can then be used to determine whether someone found guilty of a crime will immediately go to prison or not. Due to the multiple value options and my elementary knowledge, I'm having some difficulty calculating the separate variables to get the total number.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<form>
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Drug Prison In/Out Worksheet</legend>
    <div id="drugMSCO">
      <label>Most Serious Conviction Offense</label>
      <br>
      <select class="drug-in-out">
        <option>Click Here to Select from List</option>
        <option>Class A Offenses</option>
        <option value="8" class="form-control prc">Manufacturing Controlled Substance 1st Degree</option>
        <option>Class B Offenses</option>
        <option value="5" class="form-control prc">Manufacturing Controlled Substance 2nd Degree</option>
        <option value="5" class="form-control prc">Possession with Intent to Distribute Controlled Substance</option>
        <option value="6" class="form-control prc">Sale/Distribution of Marijuana</option>
        <option value="6" class="form-control prc">Sale/Distribution of Schedule I-V</option>
        <option>Class C Offenses</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">Felony DUI</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">Possession of Marijuana (per 13A-12-213(a)(1)</option>
        <option>Class D Offenses</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">Possession of Controlled Substance</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">Possession of Marijuana (per 13A-12-213(a)(2)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="drugNPAFC">
      <label>Number of Prior Adult Felony Convictions</label>
      <br>
      <select class="drug-in-out">
        <option>Click Here to Select from List</option>
        <option value="0" class="form-control prc">None</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">1</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">2</option>
        <option value="5" class="form-control prc">3</option>
        <option value="6" class="form-control prc">4</option>
        <option value="7" class="form-control prc">5</option>
        <option value="7" class="form-control prc">6</option>
        <option value="7" class="form-control prc">7</option>
        <option value="7" class="form-control prc">8</option>
        <option value="7" class="form-control prc">9</option>
        <option value="7" class="form-control prc">10 or More</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="drugNPACMV" >
      <label>Number of Prior Adult Convictions for Misdemeanors or Violations</label>
      <br>
      <select class="drug-in-out">
        <option>Click Here to Select from List</option>
        <option value="0" class="form-control prc">None</option>
        <option value="0" class="form-control prc">1</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">2</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">3</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">4</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">5</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">6</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">7</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">8</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">9</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">10 or More</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="drugPIUSI1YM">
      <label>Prior Incarcerations with Unsuspended Sentence Imposed of 1 Year or More</label>
      <br>
      <select class="drug-in-out">
        <option>Click Here to Select from List</option>
        <option value="0" class="form-control prc">No</option>
        <option value="0" class="form-control prc">Yes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="drugPFPPR">
      <label>Prior Felony Probation or Parole Revocation</label>
      <br>
      <select class="drug-in-out">
        <option>Click Here to Select from List</option>
        <option value="0"  class="form-control prc">No</option>
        <option value="1"  class="form-control prc">Yes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="drugNPJDYOA">
      <label>Number of Prior Juvenile Delinquency or YO Adjudications (Violation/Misd/Felony)</label>
      <br>
      <select class="drug-in-out">
        <option>Click Here to Select from List</option>
        <option value="0" class="form-control prc">None</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">1</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">2</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">3</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">4</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">5</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">6</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">7</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">8</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">9</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">10 or More</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="drugPUDWDI">
      <label>Possession/Use of Deadly Weapon or Dangerous Instrument</label>
      <br>
      <select class="drug-in-out">
        <option>Click Here to Select from List</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
        <option value="2">Yes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="drug-in-out">
      <label>Total In/Out Worksheet Score</label>
      <br>
      <output id="drug-io-result"></output>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
        $('.drug-in-out').on('input', '.prc', function(){
            var totalSum=0;
            $('.drug-in-out .prc').each(function()){
                var inputVal=$(this).val();
                if($.isNumeric(inputVal)){
                    totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
                }
                                        });
        $('#drug-io-result').val(totalSum);

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected each selection to produce a value that when added with the others would pop up a number next to the bottom of the screen, but no number is popping up.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - do you get a JavaScript error on the browser or console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few changes are needed:

- Change the `.on('input', ...)` to `.on('change', function(){...})`
- and change `$('.drug-in-out .prc').each(...);` with `$('.drug-in-out').each(...);`
- Also, to avoid users selecting a 'heading' in the `select`, you can `disable` them like this:

  `<option disabled>--- Class A Offenses ---</option>`

**See demo below**:

**UPDATED**

Updated, based on comments, to display a suggested value from a pre-determined array of objects based on calculated total sum.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.drug-in-out').on('change', function() {
    var totalSum = 0;
    $('.drug-in-out').each(function() {
      var inputVal = $(this).val();
      if ($.isNumeric(inputVal)) {
        totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
      }
    });

    $('#drug-io-result').val(totalSum);

    // lookup the recommended length based on guidelines
    var recommendationObject = thresholdLevels.find(function(element) {
      return isWithinRange(totalSum, element.min, element.max);
    });

    // build the output string
    var recommendationString = "Suggested Level: " + recommendationObject.level + " (" + recommendationObject.months + " months)";

    // display value on DOM
    $('#drug-io-recommendation').val(recommendationString);
  });

  // Define values for None(N), Low (L), Medium (M), High (H) thresholds
  // Please adjust these values as needed.
  var thresholdLevels = [{
      "min": 0,
      "max": 41,
      "level": "None",
      "months": 0
    },
    {
      "min": 42,
      "max": 74,
      "level": "Low",
      "months": 13
    },
    {
      "min": 75,
      "max": 109,
      /* or whatever the ceiling is here*/
      "level": "Medium",
      "months": 23
    },
    {
      "min": 110,
      /* or whatever the floor is here */
      "max": 381,
      "level": "High",
      "months": 32
    }
  ];

  // this function determines if X is within the ranges defined by min and max values
  var isWithinRange = function(x, min, max) {
    return x >= min && x <= max;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Drug Prison In/Out Worksheet</legend>
    <div id="drugMSCO">
      <label>Most Serious Conviction Offense</label>
      <br>
      <select class="drug-in-out">
        <option>Click Here to Select from List</option>
        <option disabled>--- Class A Offenses ---</option>
        <option value="8" class="form-control prc">Manufacturing Controlled Substance 1st Degree</option>
        <option disabled>--- Class B Offenses ---</option>
        <option value="5" class="form-control prc">Manufacturing Controlled Substance 2nd Degree</option>
        <option value="5" class="form-control prc">Possession with Intent to Distribute Controlled Substance</option>
        <option value="6" class="form-control prc">Sale/Distribution of Marijuana</option>
        <option value="6" class="form-control prc">Sale/Distribution of Schedule I-V</option>
        <option disabled>--- Class C Offenses ---</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">Felony DUI</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">Possession of Marijuana (per 13A-12-213(a)(1)</option>
        <option disabled>--- Class D Offenses ---</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">Possession of Controlled Substance</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">Possession of Marijuana (per 13A-12-213(a)(2)</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="drugNPAFC">
      <label>Number of Prior Adult Felony Convictions</label>
      <br>
      <select class="drug-in-out">
        <option>Click Here to Select from List</option>
        <option value="0" class="form-control prc">None</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">1</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">2</option>
        <option value="5" class="form-control prc">3</option>
        <option value="6" class="form-control prc">4</option>
        <option value="7" class="form-control prc">5</option>
        <option value="7" class="form-control prc">6</option>
        <option value="7" class="form-control prc">7</option>
        <option value="7" class="form-control prc">8</option>
        <option value="7" class="form-control prc">9</option>
        <option value="7" class="form-control prc">10 or More</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="drugNPACMV">
      <label>Number of Prior Adult Convictions for Misdemeanors or Violations</label>
      <br>
      <select class="drug-in-out">
        <option>Click Here to Select from List</option>
        <option value="0" class="form-control prc">None</option>
        <option value="0" class="form-control prc">1</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">2</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">3</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">4</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">5</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">6</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">7</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">8</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">9</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">10 or More</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="drugPIUSI1YM">
      <label>Prior Incarcerations with Unsuspended Sentence Imposed of 1 Year or More</label>
      <br>
      <select class="drug-in-out">
        <option>Click Here to Select from List</option>
        <option value="0" class="form-control prc">No</option>
        <option value="0" class="form-control prc">Yes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="drugPFPPR">
      <label>Prior Felony Probation or Parole Revocation</label>
      <br>
      <select class="drug-in-out">
        <option>Click Here to Select from List</option>
        <option value="0" class="form-control prc">No</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">Yes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="drugNPJDYOA">
      <label>Number of Prior Juvenile Delinquency or YO Adjudications (Violation/Misd/Felony)</label>
      <br>
      <select class="drug-in-out">
        <option>Click Here to Select from List</option>
        <option value="0" class="form-control prc">None</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">1</option>
        <option value="1" class="form-control prc">2</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">3</option>
        <option value="2" class="form-control prc">4</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">5</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">6</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">7</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">8</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">9</option>
        <option value="3" class="form-control prc">10 or More</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div id="drugPUDWDI">
      <label>Possession/Use of Deadly Weapon or Dangerous Instrument</label>
      <br>
      <select class="drug-in-out">
        <option>Click Here to Select from List</option>
        <option value="0">No</option>
        <option value="2">Yes</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <hr/>
    <div class="drug-in-out">
      <label>Total In/Out Worksheet Score:</label>
      <output id="drug-io-result"></output>
      <br>
      <label>Recommendation:</label>
      <output id="drug-io-recommendation"></output>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! You have no idea how long I've been stressing over this... I really appreciate it... and thanks for the tip re headings too!

Comment: @ChristopherWeaver I am glad I could help

Comment: perhaps you can help w/ one more issue. The output number is supposed to be something like a primary key for a table of possible low, medium and high sentencing lengths. (i.e.:  an output of anything from 42 to 74 would result in a low sentence suggestion of 13 months, mid level suggestion of 23 months and a high suggestion of 32 months, or  42-74: L13, M23, H32) and those suggestions depend on the output, from 42 all the way to 381. I thought of using if/else if but a friend has suggested I use object.keys, and suggested a rough code that I cannot get to work on my end.  Any advice?

Comment: @ChristopherWeaver I am a bit busy at the moment but let me see if I find a spare moment to put something together as an update to this answer

Comment: at your convenience man, thanks much. and if you cant find the time, no worries. I'm a novice who went into this thinking that i knew more than I did.

Comment: @ChristopherWeaver I updated my answer, see if that suits your needs

Comment: @ChristopherWeaver come to think of it, feel free to ask a separate question for this part (you may get other ideas from other people as well)

Comment: apologies for failing to get back with you... .this update is great, I am tweaking it a bit regarding the substance of the output, but this is exactly what I needed. I sincerely appreciate you and hope you have a great weekend.